# How to see if a proposition is consistent or inconsistent?

Tags: logic

This should be easy since I'm doing first year logic, but that's also why I can only work with a limited amount of logical tools.

The whole proposition seems very odd, but isn't it the same as:

i) I do not like to eat mango

ii) If I do eat mango, then I like to eat mango

?, which is like saying:

i) $\neg A$

ii) If $B$, then $A$

I can't see how this can be either consistent or inconsistent. To be inconsistent, it would need the assumption $B$, wouldn't it?

Comment: The way I read it was. "I do not like to hit other people, but when I do [like to hit other people] I do like [to hit other people]." which is logically consistent, if vacuous.

Comment: That may be true. I was actually discussing that same thought with a few classmates but none of us could accept it, because it seems so strange. But maybe that's where we were wrong.

Comment: Please use a better title.

Comment: I have edited the title, some grammar and added LaTeX. Please see that it is correct.

Comment: I'm afraid that after some edits, the question doesn't make sense anymore.  Which "whole proposition" seems very odd?  Isn't _what_ the same as the conjunction of (i) and (ii)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only consistent, but informative.  Your translation looks right:

1. $\neg A$
2. $B \rightarrow A$,

where $A$ is "I like to eat mango" and $B$ is "I eat mango".  A set of propositions is consistent if there's a way to assign truth values to all the terms to make all the propositions true.  (There may be more than one way that works.)  This set of propositions is consistent, as you can see by assigning $A$ and $B$ to be false.  It's also informative, because that satisfying assignment is unique: $A$ obviously has to be false, but slightly less obviously, $B$ has to be false as well.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If not $A$, then not $B$ . Can you conclude?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think so.
I mean I get how:
i) not A
ii)If B, then A
iii) If not A, then not B
is consistent, but what I don't get is where that last proposition is taken from? Is that simply an assumption that one has to make, to get anything out of this set of sentences, or?
Sorry for my lack of knowledge here, but I have only had 2 hours of logic so far.

Comment: Or wait. If I say Contraposition, am I on the right track?

Comment: @elisa It is "vacuously true" that not B.

Comment: Ok, so the statement is consistent? But, I have not yet learned about 'vacuous truth' ...

Comment: Is the whole set:
i) not A
ii) If not A, then not B
which is consistent. If that is the case, I do understand it, but if not, I think I would need a bit more help.

Answer (score 0):

It is consistent in "TEMPORAL LOGIC" when we can express statements like "I will be hungry until I eat something".

That is to say : "I do not like to eat mango, UNTIL, I do eat mango, then I like to eat mango"

which is :
1) ¬A
2) B→A